# The movie "Die Hard" or The "Die Hard" Movie?

Tags: word-order, phrase-choice

Sometime like this case I don't know if I can put the name before or after the label (`movie` in this sentence)...

> The movie "Die Hard" or The "Die Hard" Movie?
>
> The variable "X" or The "X" variable?

Are they both correct?
What is their difference?
What is the application of each?

My question is not about "the" ([like this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23277)), but the order of the "movie" and "Die Hard"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about "the" before names](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23277/question-about-the-before-names)

Comment: I've ansewered this elsewhere. Check the link on my above comment

Comment: @MaulikV Thanks but my question is different, I don't ask about "the",  I ask about the order of name and the value

Comment: it's a matter of style Ahmad.

Comment: Related: [“I hate red color” or “I hate red”: why exactly is the first option ungrammatical](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/39737/3281). -- It was unfortunate that one of the OP's examples is about movies. (People would simply call its title.) But when talking about an instance of a type, from a learner's perspective, there are too many choices, e.g.: *the color red* or *a color red* or *the red color* or *a red color* or just *color red* or just *red color* or just *red* or even *a/the color called red*! *The variable X* or perhaps just *variable X* falls into this kind of construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**...the movie *Die Hard* ...

...the *Die Hard* movie...**

Since this movie is quite a franchise, with multiple versions, we can also have

**...one of the *Die Hard* movies.**

In the first, *Die Hard* is a name in apposition to "movie".  That is how names are typically given in English:  My uncle Joe..., the movie *On the Waterfront*.

In the second, the two-word title, *Die Hard*, is used attributively as an adjective.  This, too, is possible, but the longer the title, the less likely it becomes because this form is a type of *concision*. This would not be likely: "...the *They Shoot Horses, Don't They?* movie...". The title would most likely be truncated when using this form:

**... in the *They Shoot Horses* movie...**

Comment: Then they are alternative to each other, while the first one is common?

Comment: They are both common. The second form is slightly "curt" or abrupt or "clipped".

Comment: But you would only use "the XYZ movie" if you believe XYZ is well-known to your audience, and somehow distinctive. "Die Hard", for instance, was wildly successful and spawned (at last count) 4 sequels, so the usage is appropriate (for most Americans). But it's probably not appropriate to talk about "the Primer movie" except with a rather selective bunch of SF fans.

Comment: I pretty much agree. With the *the XYZ movie* form, the speaker assumes the listener/reader is previously acquainted with the movie, either that, or the speaker has already mentioned it.